# Exclude some JARs from Web-Inf/Lib Folder

Tags: java, web-applications, ant

I'm starting with Ant. I created a `build.xml` to generate a WAR file of a Web Project and it worked OK.

Then, I made some change to exclude all *.jar from `WEB-INF/lib` Folder and also works OK.

Now I need to make the changes to exclude all JARs files, but leave some especial JARs in `WEB-INF/lib` Folder. This JARs are from other project created by me.

The idea es exclude all third parties JARs and only leave my own JARs inside `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

There is some way to do that?

All my Jars start with "fnet" so maybe I can use that to create some rule, but I don't know how to do that

This is my Build.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<project name="warConLibs" default="build-war">
    <target name="clean">
        <delete file="c:/projweb.war"/>
        <delete file="c:/projweb_sl.war"/>
    </target>   

    <target name="build-war">
        <war destfile="c:/projweb.war" webxml="./WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="./WebContent">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>            
            </fileset>

            <classes dir="./bin"/>
        </war>
    </target>

    <target name="build-war-sin-libs">
        <war destfile="c:/projweb_sl.war" webxml="./WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="./WebContent">
                <include name="**/*.*"/> 
                <exclude name="**/*.jar"/>      
            </fileset>

            <classes dir="./bin"/>
        </war>
    </target>   
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to exclude a jar file is given in the [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html). If anyone face same issue, they can refer to this link.

This example is taken from the documentation, here we are removing `jdbc1.jar` from `lib`

```
Assume the following structure in the project's base directory:

thirdparty/libs/jdbc1.jar
thirdparty/libs/jdbc2.jar
build/main/com/myco/myapp/Servlet.class
src/metadata/myapp.xml
src/html/myapp/index.html
src/jsp/myapp/front.jsp
src/graphics/images/gifs/small/logo.gif
src/graphics/images/gifs/large/logo.gif
then the war file myapp.war created with


<war destfile="myapp.war" webxml="src/metadata/myapp.xml">
  <fileset dir="src/html/myapp"/>
  <fileset dir="src/jsp/myapp"/>
  <lib dir="thirdparty/libs">
    <exclude name="jdbc1.jar"/>
  </lib>
  <classes dir="build/main"/>
  <zipfileset dir="src/graphics/images/gifs"
              prefix="images"/>
</war>


will consist of
WEB-INF/web.xml
WEB-INF/lib/jdbc2.jar
WEB-INF/classes/com/myco/myapp/Servlet.class
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
index.html
front.jsp
images/small/logo.gif
images/large/logo.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read again about the `war` Ant task: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html

The correct syntax would be:

```
<war destfile="..." webxml="...">
    <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="fnet*.jar"/>
    </lib>
    <classes dir="bin"/>
</war>
```